# Collaboration between people using two different versions of VS 2010, Express and Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tortoisesvn, visual-studio-express

Ok, I have looked around on SO and haven't been able to find an answer to this question, but forgive me if I missed one out there.  It's difficult to refine the search terms for this one.

But anyways, I have VS 2010 C# Express.  I'm planning on doing some collaboration in my code (that was made entirely in Express) with someone who owns VS 2010 Ultimate.  I have been putting off upgrading to the paid version of VS 2010 because of the price - if at all possible I would rather not upgrade.  We are going to collaborate using Tortoise SVN as our version control software.

**Will it be an issue for me to continue to work with the Express version while my collaborator works on VS 2010 Ultimate? To what degree will it be an issue, etc?**

**Follow-up question: If I have to upgrade to a paid version, would I have to upgrade to Ultimate, or would Professional be sufficient?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my collaborator and I have started work, and no issues so far.  Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and Visual Studio Express are pretty much compatible, except for the Solutions folders, as described by B Pete.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with VS 2010 yet, but can offer observations based on VS 2008, using svn for source control.

I have only had one minor issue with using both the VB Express edition and VS2008 Standard and Professional versions on the same project.  The express version does not support solution folders.  I use a solution folder to allow quick access to some configuration files from the ide.  The express version does not display the solution folder, but the remainser of the solution loads sucessfully, including all the included projects.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I wonder if anything has changed since 2008 in this regard. Anyone know out there?